# PWA is not registering service worker when added to home screen?

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

How can I fix the problem of my app not registering the service worker when I add it to the home screen, even though I have done everything correctly? Interestingly, the service worker registers when I access the app through Safari and Chrome, but not when I add it to the home screen. Below is my index.html and manifest.json.

```js
// Check if environment is iOS and safari
const userAgent = navigator.userAgent;

const isIOSMobile = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/gi.test(userAgent);
const isIOSDesktop = /Macintosh|Mac OS X|Mac_PowerPC/gi.test(userAgent);
const isSafari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

const isIOS = isIOSMobile || isIOSDesktop || isSafari;

// Check if app is added to home screen on iOS
const isStandalone = () => 'standalone' in window.navigator && (window.navigator as any).standalone;

// Determine if service worker should be registered
let shouldRegisterServiceWorker = true;

if (isIOS && !isStandalone()) {
  shouldRegisterServiceWorker = false;
} else if (!isIOS) {
  shouldRegisterServiceWorker = true;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
      <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
        {'      isIOS??   '}
        {`${isIOS}`}
      </div>
      <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
        {' isStandalone (Insalled iOS) '}
        {`${isStandalone()}`}
      </div>
      <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
        {' shouldRegisterServiceWorker '}
        {`${shouldRegisterServiceWorker}`}
      </div>
    </div>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

 
serviceWorkerRegistration.register();
serviceWorkerRegistration.unregister();


reportWebVitals();
```

```js
"start_url": "./",
"display": "standalone",
"orientation": "portrait",
"theme_color": "#3C3C3C",
"background_color": "#fff",
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 23.4.23, I have conducted tests and found that the only way to enable offline caching in standalone mode on iOS is by creating a cache manifest file in your public folder. It is unclear why there is such strictness in the iOS platform regarding offline caching, but once you implement this, you should be good to go. However, please keep in mind that you need to set your serving headers from your server to enable serving MIME TYPE compatibly. The following example is for setting the header for Firebase Hosting (static assets):

```js
"headers": [
  {
    "source": "/cache.manifest",
    "headers": [
      {
        "key": "Content-Type",
        "value": "text/cache-manifest"
      }
    ]
  }
],
```

Here is an example of a cache manifest file:

```js
CACHE MANIFEST
# Version: 1.0

CACHE:
*

NETWORK:
*

FALLBACK:
```

And to reference the cache manifest file in your HTML file, you can use the following code:

```html
<html lang="en" manifest="PUBLIC_URL%/cache.manifest">
```

Still as for the future we hope that apple will stop making PWA implantation hard and improves on it's documentation.

I am also including a react component (v4 Mui style) that will show you status of your PWA to see what is the app is caching and also whether your service worker is active or not.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

interface Props {}

export const PwaStatus: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  const [swStatus, setSwStatus] = useState(false);
  const [cachesContent, setCachesContent] = useState<string | string[]>('No Cache Found');

  useEffect(() => {
    const set = async () => {
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        await navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then((registration) => {
          setSwStatus(true);
        });
        caches.keys().then((cacheNames) => {
          setCachesContent(cacheNames);
        });
      }
    };
    set();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', color: 'white', background: 'gray', margin: 'auto' }}>
      <div>Service Worker Status</div>
      {swStatus ? <div style={{ color: 'green' }}>ServiceWorker is Active</div> : <div style={{ color: 'red' }}> ServiceWorker is Offline</div>}
      <div>Caches</div>
      {cachesContent === 'No Cache Found' ? <div style={{ color: 'red' }}>{cachesContent}</div> : <div style={{ color: 'green' }}>{cachesContent}</div>}
    </div>
  );
};
```